# A way to init sentence embedding for unsupervised text clustering, better than glove wordvec?

Tags: deep-learning, clustering, word-embeddings, embeddings, representation

For unsupervised text clustering, the key thing is the init embedding for text.

If we want to use [deepcluster](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepcluster) for text, the problem for text is how to get the init embedding from deep model.

BERT can not get good init embedding.

If we do not use deep model, is there better way to get embedding better than glove wordvec?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, GloVe gives you word embeddings, not sentence embeddings. BERT-like models can give you many things, from context-dependent wordpieces embeddings to sentence embeddings. You can also use the representation in the last layer or a combination of multiple layers...

Comment: @qmeeus average glove to get sentence embedding.

Comment: https://github.com/jx00109/sentence2vec

Comment: @DunkOnly In my experience, averaging the word embeddings to give sentence embeddings does not give good results

Answer (score 0):

Generally, combining word vectors in a single sentence / document representation does not work extremely well, although the average embedding has been used in [fastText](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01759) and pooling [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09843).

You can also use autoencoders to try and predict the word distribution, similar to a bag-of-words approach, like [here](https://gitlab.com/qmeeus/master-thesis/-/blob/fecd6132e7dcf8c98c6b265798df97486ae3baa4/thesis.pdf).